# Error when using System.Directoryservices on 2008 R2 under a non-administrator account

Tags: vb.net, directoryservices, directoryentry

I have a program that is using `system.directoryservices` and the `directorysearcher`.

On 2003 R2 this works as any user account, and only lists what they have rights to see. 
On 2008 R2, however, it only works as a user that is an administrator of the local server, not as normal user accounts.

The error I am getting is

`0x80070035 "The specified network path was not found"`

when trying to create a `searchresultcollection`.

The first part that appears to be failing is at

`system.directoryservices.directoryentry.bind(boolean throwIfFail)` but it works when I am logged in as myself with administrative credentials.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your LDAP path that you're trying to connect to?? Can you show us the code that you use to create your `SearchResultCollection` ?? What version of the .NET framework do you target??

Comment: Ok, turns out it works when the executable is on the local system but not when it is on the network, only when run as a non-domain admin. it works fine when run from the network as a domain admin.

Comment: Yeah, that's standard .NET behavior - see [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827670/net-assembly-runs-in-partial-trust-on-network-drive-but-all-other-in-full-trust) or this [WIKI entry](https://julianscorner.com/wiki/programming/caspol_network_share) on limited trust when running stuff from a network share....

Comment: As of .NET 3.5 SP1 you'll get full trust even when running from a share.  Which version of the .NET framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While I know this problem was listed a while ago, I was having a similar problem too, with the same 0x80070035 error for my logon script using Windows 8.1

```
Set UserObj = GetObject("WinNT://" & DomainString & "/" & UserString)
```

As it turns out, I was using a different DNS to what the rest of the office was using. I had the Google one of 8.8.8.8. When I took it off, the logon script worked again and I was able to get back all of my mapped drives.

I just thought I'd share my fix.