# Application configuration file error at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

The context :

I have an winform application which is launch by users on the local network (path: `\\file-01\appsdeploy$\MyApp` )

When I launch the app, it's ok it worked well. But on some other computer it does not work. I have this exception :

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for
>   MySection: Request failed.

The declaration of the section in the app.config file is :

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="MySection" type="MyGenerator.Config.MySection, MyGenerator"/>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MySectionGenerator.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
```

Now the section :

```
<MySection>
  <Addresses>
    <add Name="1" Text="ADDRESS ONE"/>
    <add Name="2" Text="ADDRESS TWO"/>
    <add Name="3" Text="ADDRESS THREE"/>
    <add Name="4" Text="ADDRESS FOUR"/>
    <add Name="5" Text="ADDRESS FIVE"/>
    <add Name="6" Text="ADDRESS SIX"/>
    <add Name="7" Text="ADDRESS SEVEN"/>
  </Addresses>
</MySection>
```

**NOTE :** If I copy the executable and the config file on the local computer, it works fine.

Have you got an idea, a clue... ?

Comment: Could it be related to the exe being "blocked" because it's run from the network drive. As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528862/why-does-using-configurationmanager-getsection-cause-securityexception-request

Comment: Only for few machines and not all ?

Comment: Maybe a difference in one or more security settings between the machines and/or user privileges?

Comment: You're right that's it ! I don't why but when I replace Section addressConfigSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection") as MySection;
by
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
MySection addressConfigSection = config.GetSection("MySection") as MySection;

Answer (score 0):

Check with allowExeDefinition=machinetoapplication option.