# Windows 8 - Assembly does not allow partially trusted caller

Tags: .net, exception, .net-assembly

We copied the binary folder of our application onto a shared directory within our company network.

We allways could start the application there to test it. Now it still works everywhere but on a new laptop with Windows8 installed we get following error:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: 
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers
```

Now i figured out this has to do that dll's used in the app don't 'trust' eachother.  But i have no clue why this happens on just 1 machine.  All other devices can start the application like this without any issues.

I hope the problem is clear if not ask away ;)

Comment: Please see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827670/net-assembly-runs-in-partial-trust-on-a-network-drive-but-all-other-in-full-tr.

Comment: Thnx i'll try them out on monday back @ work :)