# Error CS0006: Application runs locally but not from server

Tags: c#, tfs, build

I have an application that is built from a TFS Build server into a drop folder. The application builds with no errors reported.  The application is in C# using .NET 4.5.1.

When I copy the deployment folder to my local desktop, the application runs fine.

However, when I copy the deployment folder to our internal server, I get the following error when trying to run:

> error CS0006: Metadata file
>   'file:\NNNNSERVER\YourEXEFolder\log4net.DLL' could not be found

This error is repeated for all DLL's in the project and for the executable itself.

Other applications with similar profiles (C#, .NET 4.5.1) run fine on the same server. It seems to me to be pretty clear that its not the build or the code but something with the server or permissions, but I need to find something to tell our systems people.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, are you running the application on your local machine from the server's disk, or are you actually starting the program on the server? The path looks like it may be the former...?

Comment: Running on my local machine from the server.  I'm not remoting or otherwise logging into the server, just connecting through file explorer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4828205/477878) _could_ be your problem.