# Network Trust .Net App

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to run a third party tool from a network location and am running into issues with the internet trust.
I will be running the tool on Amazon machines which are automatically started\shutdown, I can not modify the internet trust settings of these machines.

I can see from [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827670/net-assembly-runs-in-partial-trust-on-a-network-drive-but-all-other-in-full-tr) that CASPOL.exe is a workaround.
Will CASPOL work on Windows Server under a default setup?
Is it possible to modify the applications config file?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at [removed]

The granted set of the failing assembly was:
<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
               version="1">
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Read="USERNAME"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Unrestricted="true"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Read="[removed]"
                PathDiscovery="[removed]"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.IsolatedStorageFilePermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Allowed="AssemblyIsolationByUser"
                UserQuota="9223372036854775807"
                Expiry="9223372036854775807"
                Permanent="True"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Flags="ReflectionEmit"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Flags="Assertion, Execution, BindingRedirects"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Unrestricted="true"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Unrestricted="true"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingPermission, System.Drawing, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                version="1"
                Level="DefaultPrinting"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Diagnostics.EventLogPermission, System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1">
      <Machine name="."
               access="Instrument"/>
   </IPermission>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.UrlIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Url="file://[removed]"/>
   <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.ZoneIdentityPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                version="1"
                Zone="Intranet"/>
</PermissionSet>
```

Comment: "from a network location" - why? Do you actually need partial trust enforced?

Comment: I am running these tools on a third party system which is in turn running them from a network drive.